# Find the products contributing to the 50% of the total sales using SQL SUM window Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

There are two Tables - **orders** and **item_line**

**orders**

| order_id | created_at | total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-11-11 13:40:50 | 450.00 |
| 124 | 2022-10-30 00:40:50 | 1500.00 |

**item_line**

| order_id | product_id | product_name | quantity | unit_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | a1b | milo | 4 | 100.00 |
| 123 | c2d | coke | 5 | 10.00 |
| 124 | c2d | coke | 150 | 10.00 |

**The question is:**
Find the products contributing to the 50% of the total sales.

My take on this is -

```
SELECT i.product_name,SUM(o.total_amount)AS 'Net Sales'
FROM item_line i
JOIN orders o on o.order_id = i.order_id
GROUP BY i.product_name
HAVING SUM(o.total_amount) = (SUM(o.total_amount)*0.5);
```

But this is not correct. SUM windows functions need to be used, but how?

Comment: In query you are trying to find orders contribution and not product SUM(o.total_amount). Here total amount is of particular orderId

Comment: It sounds like you want to pick the minimal TOP(N) products that together contribute at least 50% of sales. For the case of ten products contributing 25%, 20%, 15%, 10%, and the rest 5% each, you want to pick the top 3 covering 50% of sales (actually 60% in this case). Is that correct? If so, It sounds like you need to start with your grouping above, order by Net Sales Descending, generate a running total, find the first running total >= 50%, and then select all products up to and including that product.

Comment: `50% of the total sales.` does sales mean 'total_amount' of the order_id?; say you have 3 line items, each $30 (total_amount:$90); what would you like to see as output?

Comment: A variation of the above that might be simpler: Start with your grouping above, order by Net Sales ascending, generate a running total of Net Sales, exclude all with a running total <= 50%. The remaining products should be the minimal set having total sales >= 50%. The running total would be your window function.

Comment: A possible correction to your initial query: You should be summing price x quantity from the line items, not sum of the order total amount. This calculation need not involve the orders table at all, although in practice, you might eventually want to apply additional conditions such as an order date range.

Comment: The output should have the following columns - Product Name, Total Sales of the Product, Total Sales, Percent Share.

Comment: @Atif - Please make an attempt using the above suggestions to build an updated query. If you still have problems, update your initial post with your latest version along with a description of where you are having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, explanation is within the query comments:

```
-- find the the total sales for each product
WITH product_sales AS
(
  SELECT product_id, product_name, 
         SUM(quantity * unit_price) AS product_tot_sales
  FROM item_line
  GROUP BY product_id, product_name
),
-- find the running sales percentage for each product starting from porduct with highest sales value
running_percentage AS
(
  SELECT product_id, product_name, product_tot_sales,
         SUM(product_tot_sales) OVER (ORDER BY product_tot_sales DESC) /
         SUM(product_tot_sales) OVER () AS running_sales_percentage,
         SUM(product_tot_sales) OVER () AS tot_sales
  FROM product_sales
)
-- select products that have a running sales percentage less than the min(running_sales_percentage) where running_sales_percentage >= 0.5
-- this will select all of products that contributes of 0.5 of the total sales
SELECT product_id, product_name, product_tot_sales,
       tot_sales,
       running_sales_percentage 
FROM running_percentage
WHERE running_sales_percentage <= 
      (
       SELECT MIN(running_sales_percentage) 
       FROM running_percentage 
       WHERE running_sales_percentage >= 0.5
      )
```

You don't need a join with orders table, all data you need is existed in the item_line table.

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hBPhWNR-).